# rails active_shipping Fedex rate request fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedex

I'm trying to get shipping rate from fedex with a active_shipping gem:

```
packages = [
  Package.new(
    100,                        # 100 grams
    [93,10],                    # 93 cm long, 10 cm diameter
    :cylinder => true),         # cylinders have different volume calculations

  Package.new(
    (7.5 * 16),     # 7.5 lbs, times 16 oz/lb.
    [15, 10, 4.5],              # 15x10x4.5 inches
    :units => :imperial
    )        # not grams, not centimetres
]

origin = Location.new(
  :country => 'US',
  :state => 'CA',
  :city => 'Beverly Hills',
  :zip => '90210'
)

destination = Location.new(
  :country => 'CA',
  :province => 'ON',
  :city => 'Ottawa',
  :postal_code => 'K1P 1J1'
)

options = {
  :login => '***',
  :password => '***',
  :key => '***',
  :account => '***',
  :meter => '***',
  :test => true
}

fedex = FedEx.new(options)

rates = fedex.find_rates(origin, destination, packages)
```

But I got 803 Error:

ERROR - 803: Meter number is missing or invalid.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795902/active-shipping-fedex-api-authentication-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you passing valid credentials?

```
options = {
  :login => '***',
  :password => '***',
  :key => '***',
  :account => '***',
  :meter => '***',
  :test => true
}
```

When setting up credentials at the FedEx Dev site it will provide test credentials and production credentials. Make sure you're using the proper test meter #.